# Is there absolotely no relation between R/S configurations and d/l optical rotations?

Tags: stereochemistry

Is there such a relation between R/S configurations and d/l optical rotation that, if we experimentally know that R configuration of a fixed compound gives 'l' rotation then can we infer that the S configuration(or the mirror image) of the same compund must give 'd' rotation?

Comment: Well, yes, that much is obvious. But beyond that there is no relation.

Answer (score 2):

Note that *R/S* notation is mostly for tetrahedral chiral centers. You can have an inherently chiral structure, with chiral substituent that does not cause big optical rotation change.

E.g.
6<sup>I</sup>-*O*-[(2***R***)-butan-2-yl]-[α-cyclodextrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-Cyclodextrin) and
6<sup>I</sup>-*O*-[(2***S***)-butan-2-yl]-α-cyclodextrin

[image]

will probably have very similar optical rotations, with the same sign.

However these are diastereomers, not enantiomers, but you did explicitly require them. It's just to mention that there can be a catch.

Also note that *d/l* descriptor are now strongly discouraged ans (+) or (−) should be used, instead.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no simple relationship that links the R,S configuration to the direction of optical rotation**

The rotation of polarised light by optically active compounds is caused because linearly polarised light can be though of as a combination of (mathematically speaking the two are equivalent) two opposite circularly polarised light beams and they are themselves chiral (think of the fields as forming a spiral in space: spirals have handedness). The chiral molecule reacts differently with light of different chirality (as chiral molecules do with their enantiomers). This is one way to explain the interaction of light and chiral molecules.

But that interaction is complicated to explain (you need a fair amount of quantum mechanical math to talk about it at all). Moreover there is no simple way to tell from a know chirality in a molecule which *direction* it will rotate light.

But we do know that, whichever direction one chiral molecules rotates light, its enantiomer will rotate light by the same amount but in the *opposite* direction. Beyond that we have no simple models to tell us the magnitude or the direction of rotation even when we know the absolute configuration of the chirality of the molecule.